# Aggregating data table in R with information outside the table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like as below, and I would like to aggregate all the values within a 5s time range of another vector of timestamp.

If my description confuses you, please see the following toy example

```
trade_hist <-data.table(timestamp=seq(1,200,2),value=rep(1:5,20))
TS <- seq(2,200,2)
> head(trade_hist)
   timestamp value
1:         1     1
2:         3     2
3:         5     3
4:         7     4
5:         9     5
6:        11     1
> head(TS)
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12
```

I eventually want to create new table with timetamp as in TS and aggregate the values in original table with certain condition (say sum up all values within 5s time range prior to that time stamp). I can accomplish this with the following code:

```
list_of_values <- vector("list",length(TS))
for(i in 1:length(TS)){
        ts <- TS[i]
        tmp <- trade_hist[(ts-timestamp <= 5) & ts-timestamp > 0]        
        tmp <- tmp[,.(sumVal=sum(value))]
        list_of_values[[i]] <- tmp
}

newcol <- rbindlist(list_of_values)
result_wanted <- cbind(TS,newcol)

> head(result_wanted)
   TS sumVal
1:  2      1
2:  4      3
3:  6      6
4:  8      9
5: 10     12
6: 12     10
```

For example, when TS=6, look back to the original table for 5s range prior to that we have value=1,2,3 thereby the sum is 6; when TS=8, look back to the original table we have value=2,3,4, sum is 9.

However the code above is extremely inefficient for bigger table, is there some other way around? Thx!

Comment: This isn't very reproducible.

Comment: Please edit with a `dput` of your data. Generally, those operations look vectorizable, though; just run the same thing without the loop.

Comment: Would you make your example much smaller and show your desired output?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Description edited. Please help!

Comment: @alistaire It will be great if you can provide an example of vectorizing this. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @MichaelChirico for suggesting forverlap
I wrote a solution for my question using forverlap and it is really quick!

```
x <- data.table(start=TS,end=TS)
y <- trade_hist[,.(start=timestamp,end=timestamp+5,value)]
setkey(y, start, end)
tmp <- foverlaps(x, y, type="within")
result <- tmp[,.(value=sum(value)),by=i.start]
setnames(result,"i.start","timestamp")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`,

```
sumVal <- sapply(TS, function(x){
    sum(trade_hist %>% 
        filter(timestamp >= x-5, timestamp <= x) %>% 
        select(value))
})
result_wanted <- data.frame(TS, sumVal)
```

which will be considerably faster than the original. `data.table` or `Rcpp` could probably make it faster yet, if your data is truly huge.

Keep in mind that if `TS` and `trade_hist$timestamp` are actually date-time objects, they need to be in a format that can handle subtraction and greater than/less than operators, or those operations need to be changed to a suitable one. `lubridate` or `chron` probably has what you need if the base `POSIXlt`/`POSIXct` isn't cutting it.

Comment: Thx but I think my version is faster than this...I checked with lager table

Comment: If you wrap `trade_hist` in `dplyr::tbl_df`, mine cuts its time by 2/3 to 10-15% faster than the original. Honestly, I'm kind of impressed by the performance of the `for`-loop; they can get much slower. Really, if time is the primary consideration, `Rcpp` is the play, but that's beyond my current expertise.

Comment: *also change `data.frame(TS, sumVal)` back to `cbind(TS, sumVal)` for max speed. Print format is slightly different, but the data is the same.

Comment: Specifying argument names helps, too. 30% faster: `sumVal <- sapply(X = TS, FUN = function(x){sum(select(.data = filter(.data = trade_hist, ... = timestamp >= x-5 & timestamp <= x), ... = value))})` Also see [this post](http://rstatistics.net/strategies-to-speed-up-r-code/) for more options.